# QGIS 3 crashes when trying to download semi-automatic classification plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, scp

Installed QGIS 3 in prescribed manner. (i.e. FIRST python, then GDAL, then QGIS 3).
Then installed matplotlib manually by typing "sudo pip3 install matplotlib" into terminal.
Then, (as per instructions on https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/plugin-installation2.html) I went to  https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python/  to download:

- NumPy 1.9.2-1
- SciPy 0.16.0-1

Did not download matplotlib 1.4.3-1 because I believe I installed that when I typed "sudo pip3 install matplotlib" into terminal.

Rebooted macbook (OS 10.14.2)
Started QGIS 3 alright.
Went into manage plugins and clicked : "re-install semi-automatic classification plugin". QGIS 3 just **crashed**.

What's going on ?

Comment: is better that you report a issue https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/issues

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by doing:

1. sudo apt-get install python3-pip
2. pip3 install numpy
3. pip3 install scipy